# Frog species identification

Tags: species-identification

A friend of mine came across this frog today. I'm not too familiar with frogs, can someone ID this? *Please forgive my friend's abysmal use of English..*

Location: Central Kentucky, USA.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is a [Pickerel Frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickerel_frog) - *Lithobates palustris*

Here some more pictures and habitat type
http://www.californiaherps.com/noncal/misc/miscfrogs/pages/l.palustris.html

[image]